# Как вставить изображение в кнопку? pyQt5

Tags: python, изображения, button, pyqt5

Создал кнопку. Необходимо вставить в неё изображение (растянуть по всей кнопке), как это можно сделать?

```
but = QPushButton(self)
```

И что дальше?

Comment: Вы смотрели альтернативные варианты конструктора `QPushButton` в документации?

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to set image on QPushButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3137805/4279)

Answer (score 5):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Image')
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 640, 480)

        but = QPushButton(self)
        but.setIcon(QIcon('image.jpg'))
        but.setIconSize(QSize(75, 75))
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Как-то так